# Как отсортировать и вывести таблицу с parent и child записями?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Нужно получить выборку содержащую parent'ы и список child'ов под ней.
Пытался использовать WITH, но получаю не то, что нужно

```
WITH PatronCon (id, parent_id)
AS
(SELECT
   id,
   parent_id
 FROM PatronContact
 WHERE parent_id IS NULL
 UNION ALL
 SELECT
   t1.id,
   t1.parent_id
 FROM PatronContact t1
   JOIN PatronCon t2 ON t1.parent_id = t2.id
)
SELECT *
FROM PatronCon
```

В итоге из таблицы с такими данными

```
id  parent_id
--- -------
1   null
2   1
3   1
4   null
5   4
6   4
7   1
8   4
```

Нужно получить такой ответ

```
id  parent_id
--- -------
1   null
2   1
3   1
7   1
4   null
5   4
6   4
8   4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN parent_id IS NULL THEN id ELSE parent_id END, parent_id, id
```